# Setting MAC adress in ":" format fails through bash script

Tags: bash, format, setting

I am trying to set the MAC address through the bash script. It fails if i have it in ":" format.

I have simplified the program to convey the issue.
in mac.sh i have  the following :

```
mac="00:22:33:12:10:10"
echo "ifconfig eth1 hw ether $mac"
cmd="ifcfg eth1 hw ether $mac"
echo "cmd:" $cmd
```

The output is :

```
ifconfig eth1 hw ether 00:22:33:12:10:10
cmd: ifcfg eth1 hw ether 00 22 33 12 10 10
```

My question is why is the output in the second different. Shouldn't it be the same as 00:22:33:12:10:10 ?

Comment: Have you by any chance set `IFS=:`? That would cause the unquoted `$cmd` to undergo word-splitting on the colons, and `echo` outputs each of its arguments separated by a space.

Comment: @chepner, yes , i do have IFS:. Once i remove this then it is working ok. But IFS is not on this variable though. It is on a different variable.See the attached snippet:                                                                                         array=()
for (( CNTR=0; CNTR<${#mac}; CNTR+=2 )); do
  array+=( ${mac:CNTR:2} )
done
IFS=':'
calculated_mac_address="${array[*]}"
echo "$calculated_mac_address"


tempmac="00:02:35:12:10:10"
echo "ifconfig eth1 hw ether $tempmac"
cmd="ifcfg eth1 hw ether $tempmac"
echo "cmd:" $cmd

Comment: It's impossible to tell from that comment whether you have an issue or not (newlines matter here). However, you are mistaken if you think putting `IFS=':'` prior to an assignment limits the change to that assignment. An assignment is not a command, so you appear to just have two global assignments `IFS=':'` and `calculated_mac_address="${array[*]}"` on one line.